# How to get an image from Cloudinary using its React SDK

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I'm trying to follow the Cloudinary [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_integration#get_started_with_react) to get started with the React SDK. I've already uploaded an image and now I want to retrieve and edit it. I'm stuck on the retrieval bit. I've replicated the tutorial as per:

```js
  // Create a Cloudinary instance and set your cloud name.
  const cld = new Cloudinary({
    cloud: {
      cloudName: myCloudName,
    },
  });

  // Use the image with public ID, 'front_face'.
  const myImage = cld.image("samples/cld-sample-5");
```

I've changed the `cloudName` as per the `cloudName` in my dashboard. I've then changed the `public ID` to a sample image in my Media Library:

[image]

Unfortunately I keep getting a 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Public ID](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#public_id) on Cloudinary is the asset's identifier and it'll contain a filename (could be a randomly generated string of characters or the actual filename of the asset) + any containing folder(s). In this case, and based on your screenshot, the `cld-sample-5` asset is in the root folder but you're requesting it by passing the public_id set to `samples/cld-sample-5` so unless you have an asset in the `samples` folder called `cld-sample-5`, the expected response is 404 as no asset exists for that public_id. If you want to target the `cld-sample-5` asset then your public_id (that is passed to the `image()` method) should just be `cld-sample-5`.

In addition, in Cloudinary, an asset is unique/identified by not only the 'public_id' but only when that is in combination with the ['resource_type'](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#asset_types) ('image', 'video' or 'raw') and ['type'](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#delivery_types) (e.g. 'upload', 'private', 'authenticated', 'fetch' etc). Therefore the below assets with the same public_id (sample) are actually different entities:

```
image/upload/sample
image/private/sample
video/upload/sample
video/authenticated/sample
```

The public_id is returned in the response for each successful upload and you can store the 'public_id', 'resource_type' and 'type' parameters in your database and then you can reference any asset on Cloudinary both for delivery and via the API.

Finally, API methods, such as `upload()` and others, default the value of certain optional parameters if they are not provided. This includes the 'resource_type' (defaulted to "image") and also 'type' (defaulted to "upload"). This is why if you're uploading a "video" rather than an image, you will either need to pass `resource_type: "video"` or `resource_type: "auto"` to the upload() method - otherwise it'll default to "image" resource_type and you'll get an error back.

Comment: Aw man you're totally right. Such a dumb mistake on my part. I had clicked on the 'samples' folder and had assumed I was looking at it, but turns out you need to double click to open the folder. So much time spent looking in all the wrong places!